# The pushout of an epimorphism is an epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, epimorphisms

I'm reading the book "Handbook of Categorical Algebra: Volume 1, Basic Category Theory" by Francis Borceux, and in page 52 he states that

> "..."the pullback of a monomorphism is a monomorphism". The dual notion of a "pullback" is that of a "pushout". In particular, "the pushout of an epimorphism is an epimorphism"..."

how can I show this last statement directly?

Comment: This is one of these proofs where everything falls into place as soon as you write down the definitions. Try to do it yourself before looking at the answer, it will be very beneficial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So suppose

$$\begin{array}
AA & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & C \\
\downarrow{f} & & \downarrow{\beta} \\
B & \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} & D  
\end{array}$$
is a pushout and $f$ is epi. We will show that $\beta$ is epi. Suppose, $h_1, h_2 \colon D \to D'$ are such that $h_1 \beta = h_2 \beta$. We have 
$$ h_1\alpha f = h_1 \beta g = h_2\beta g = h_2 \alpha f $$
As $f$ is epi, we have $h_1 \alpha = h_2 \alpha$. Now, as we have a pushout, there is a unique(!) $h \colon D \to D'$ such that $h\alpha = h_1\alpha = h_2\alpha$ and $h\beta = h_1 \beta = h_2 \beta$. As $h_1$ and $h_2$ both have this property, $h_1 = h_2$ and $\beta$ is epi.