# Seifert-van Kampen theorem with surjective homomorphism induced by inclusion

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I got a problem with Exercise 70.2 from *Munkres' Topology*.

The situation is:

$X= U \cup V$, where $U$, $V$: open, and path connected, $U \cap V$ is also path connected. $x_{0} \in U \cap V$ is a point.
$$i_{1}: \pi_{1} (U \cap V, x_{0}) \rightarrow \pi_{1} (U, x_{0}),$$
$$i_{2}: \pi_{1} (U \cap V, x_{0}) \rightarrow \pi_{1} (V, x_{0}),$$
$$j_{1}: \pi_{1} (U, x_{0}) \rightarrow \pi_{1} (X, x_{0}),$$
$$j_{2}: \pi_{1} (V, x_{0}) \rightarrow \pi_{1} (X, x_{0}),$$
are the homomorphisms induced by inclusions.

What I want to prove is:

> If $i_{2}$ is surjective, then $j_{1}$ is surjective.

The rest of the solution becomes almost trivial if this is true.
I first tried to prove this by merely using the surjectivity of $i_{2}$ as a map, but I didn't get the proof.

So I tried to use that $j: \pi_{1} (U) \ast \pi_{2} (V) \rightarrow \pi_{1} (X)$ induced by $j_{1}$ and $j_{2}$ is surjective and $\pi_{1}(V)$ is generated by $\pi_{1} (U \cap V)$, and etc, but still I don't have no idea.

I think this question is merely an algebraic question. An hint will help me very much. Thank you.

Comment: The pushout of an epimorphism is again an epimorphism. You're right that it's a purely algebraic question. In fact it can be proved with a diagram chase.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1299497/16490

Comment: Hmm... I only know that epimorphism = surjective homomorphism but it seems that categorical definition helps. Thank you.

Comment: If you would like us to repeat that proof in the concrete category of groups here, with surjections instead of epimorphisms, just ask. we can certainly do that.

Comment: Oh your reply was enough for me. I understood the proof in that link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with category theory. But it's fairly easy to prove with existing material in Munkres.

Theorem 59.1 says that $j_{1*}$ and $j_{2*}$ generate $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. But since $i_2$ is surjective, every element of $\pi_1(V,x_0)$ can be written as $i_2(g)$ where $g \in \pi_1(U \cap V)$. Since $j_2 \circ i_2 (g) = j_1 \circ i_1 (g)$, $j_{1*}$ generates $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.

The rest of the exercise is to show $M \subset \ker j_2$, which is easy.