# Pushout of isomorphism is isomorphism.

Tags: category-theory

So we have a situation where $f$ is an isomorphism and we take the pushout of $f$ and $g$ to get this.

[image]

I want to show that $h$ is an isomorphism.

Universal property with below square gives $k$ such that $kh = id$. (and $kj = gf^{-1}$)

I'm having trouble seeing why $hk = id$ too.

[image]

From here, I know that pushout preserves epimorphism: [The pushout of an epimorphism is an epimorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299488/the-pushout-of-an-epimorphism-is-an-epimorphism)

So in a category like Set, I would have that $h$ is indeed isomorphism, but I want to know of a way to see $hk = id$ in general.

Thanks

Comment: A more conceptual proof is: the pushout is functorial in the morphism, hence preserves isomorphisms. It is a good exercise to work out what this means in detail and then prove it. And I think that you need *less effort* to prove this than the special statement about isomorphisms. Also, this more general statement is used in other contexts is well (sometimes it's called the "pasting lemma").

Comment: The "low level" proof of this would be: $(hk) \circ h = \operatorname{id} \circ h$ and $(hk) \circ j = \operatorname{id} \circ j$, so the uniqueness part of the pushout property implies $hk = \operatorname{id}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to show $B$ is the pushout (up to isomorphism) we can just show that $B$ satisfies the universal property! So knowing that $g$ is an iso from $A$ to $\widetilde{A}$, we can follow our nose and guess what the other maps will be:

[image: the pushout]

First, note the square obviously commutes. Next, we assume $C$ is any other object, and $h$ and $k$ satisfy $kf = hg$. We want to show there is a unique arrow from the lower $B$ (the purported pushout) making the whole diagram commute.

But since the right leg of our square is $1$, we *do* have a unique choice of arrow to make the right triangle commute! We have to choose $k$ for our dotted arrow.

So all that's left is to verify that choosing $k$ here makes the left triangle commute as well,
but that amounts to checking $kfg^{-1} = h$, which is true since we're assuming $kf = hg$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: hmmm, so I see that the 2nd diagram in my question is a pushout, but how does that show that $k$ in my question is isomorphism?

Comment: @Phil It shows that $h$ in your question is an isomorphism, since it's the identity arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Alltough the other answer is correct I thought it would be worthwhile to give a more detailed answer:

You are considering the following pushout diagram, where $f$ is an isomorphism,

[image: pushout diagram]

and you have proven that $h$ has a left inverse. For completeness I include the proof of this:

Since $f$ is an isomorphism we can construct morphisms $gf^{-1}\colon C \to B$ and the identity $1_B \colon B \to B$. Notice that $1_Bg = gf^{-1}f$, so by the universal property of pushouts, there is a unique morphism $k\colon D \to B$ such that $kj=gf^{-1}$ and $kh=1_B$.

Now what remains to prove is that $hk = 1_D$:

We have that
$$(hk)j = h(kj) = h(gf^{-1}) = (hg)f^{-1} = jff^{-1}=j$$
and
$$(hk)h = h(kh) = h1_B=h,$$
so $hk$ fits into the commutative diagram below

[image: universal property of pushout]

The universal property of a pushout says that the dashed arrow making the digram commute is unique. Since the diagram would commute if the dashed arrow was the identity, it must be the case that $hk$ is the identity.

Thus $kh = 1_B$ and $hk = 1_D$, so $h$ is an isomorphism.