# Pushouts preserve homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Consider the following diagram in $\mathbf{Top}$:
\begin{array}
AA & \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} & B \\
\downarrow{f} & & \downarrow{g} \\
C & \stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow} & D  
\end{array}
and suppose that it is a pushout. How can I show that $f$ being an homeomorphism implies that $g$ must be also?

I think that this boils down to pushouts preserving isomorphisms, but I couldn't find a proof for it.

Comment: Are you able to show that $B$ satisfies the universal property of a pushout?

Comment: Can you elaborate what it means for $B$ to satisfy the universal property? I know that this diagram satisfies the universal property since it was given to be a pushout. @Claudius

Comment: Do you mean that this diagram is a pushout? 
$$
\begin{array}
AA & \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} & B \\
\uparrow{f^{-1}} & & \uparrow{h \circ f^{-1}} \\
C & \stackrel{\operatorname{id}}{\longrightarrow} & C  
\end{array}
$$ @ronno

Comment: What I mean is, that your diagram for $D = B$, $g = \mathrm{id_B}$ and $k = h\circ f^{-1}$ is a pushout diagram.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4160501/pushout-of-isomorphism-is-isomorphism

Comment: Another possible approach: use the pushout property of the given diagram involving $A,B,C,D$ to show there exists a unique morphism $D \to B$ whose composition with $k$ is equal to $h \circ f^{-1}$ and whose composition with $g$ is equal to $\operatorname{id}_B$.  It would then remain to show that the composition with $g$ in the other order is equal to $\operatorname{id}_D$ also.

Comment: @Claudius what can I do with this information then?

Comment: Pushouts are unique up to unique isomorphism. Hence, if you know that $B$ is a pushout of the diagram $C \leftarrow A \to B$, then you get an isomorphism $B \cong D$ from the universal property.

Comment: And this will directly imply that it's exactly $g$ that is the isomorphism $B \cong D$? @Claudius

Comment: Yes, the universal property tells you what the isomorphism is, call it $\gamma \colon B\to D$. One of its requirements is that $\gamma \circ \mathrm{id}_B = g$, so necessarily $\gamma = g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clean up the comments:

The maps $hf^{-1}:C\to B,1_B:B\to B$ induce (why?) a map $\lambda:D\to B$ which in particular satisfies $\lambda g=1_B$ (existence). To show $g\lambda=1_D$, we use the uniqueness part of the universal property of a pushout square. Simply check that $g\lambda$ and $1_D$ have the same components when ‘restricted’ to $B$ and $C$.

This works in any category. Exercise: do the same and show a pullback of an isomorphism is again an isomorphism. Prove this directly and prove this as a corollary of the result for pushouts.

Comment: So $\lambda$ is induced by the fact that, then $B$ is a pushout of the diagram $A \xleftarrow{f^{-1}} C \xrightarrow{hf^{-1}} B$? @FShrike

Comment: @NathanielJohonson In my setup $\lambda$ has domain $D$, not $B$, so a pushout with tip $B$ would not be relevant. $\lambda$ is induced from the pushout square the question gives you, the one with $f,k,g,h,A,B,C,D$.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more abstractly, this is because pushout is a left adjoint. For convenience, consider the dual statement, i.e. that pullback is a right adjoint. More precisely, for any $f:A\to B$, taking the pullback along $f$ is a functor from the slice category $C/B$ to the slice $C/A$. This functor has always as left adjoint the composition with $f$. From this, since right adjoint preserve limits, taking the pullback along $f$ preserves terminal objects in the slice, but in a slice category an object is terminal iff it is an iso in the base category, thus the pullback of an iso is iso. Your statement then follows by doing this proof in C^op.